# Depend on git repository in setup.py

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to make a project depend on a git dependency. However, I can't seem to get it to work. What I basically want to achieve is the following, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.0.0',
    install_requires=[
        'git+https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan.git'
    ])
```

I tried several variations on the above, such as adding `@master` or `#egg=wakeonlan-0.2.2`, but this doesn't make a difference.

The following works, but only when using the deprecated `pip` flag, `--process-dependency-links`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.0.0',
    install_requires=[
        'wakeonlan'
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'git+https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan.git#egg=wakeonlan-0.2.2'
    ])
```

This outputs:

```
$ pip install --no-index -e . --process-dependency-links
Obtaining file:///home/remco/Downloads/spam
  DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting wakeonlan (from spam==0.0.0)
  Cloning https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan.git to /tmp/pip-build-mkhpjcjf/wakeonlan
  DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Installing collected packages: wakeonlan, spam
  Running setup.py install for wakeonlan ... done
  Running setup.py develop for spam
Successfully installed spam wakeonlan-0.2.2
```

The following does work:

```
pip install 'git+https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan.git'
```

Also adding the git url in a requirements file just works.

Is there any **non deprecated** way to depend on a git url using a `setup.py` file?

Comment: No, that answers suggests using the deprecated dependency_links.

Comment: a related github issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2023 - however I did not see a solution there yet.

Comment: At the moment, it would seem there isn't a non-deprecated way to do this :\

Answer (score 6):

Pip >= 9.1 [(commit 6ec559)](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/6ec55979300c836e35c2ac1b99bc1c78d96baef2) will have support for the new `@` syntax as described in [PEP508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/), which takes the format: `pkgname@url#sum` - e.g.:

```
pip install --no-index packaging@https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2b/c681de3e1dbcd469537aefb15186b800209aa1f299d933d23b48d85c9d56/packaging-15.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ce1a869fe039fbf7e217df36c4653d1dbe657778b2d41709593a0003584405f4
```

This will also be useable in setup.py in the same way, e.g.:

```
install_requires=['packaging@https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2b/c681de3e1dbcd469537aefb15186b800209aa1f299d933d23b48d85c9d56/packaging-15.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ce1a869fe039fbf7e217df36c4653d1dbe657778b2d41709593a0003584405f4']
```

You can try this out just now with the latest commit to `pip` master (updating pip the 'wrong' way!):

```
$ pip install https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip
$ pip install --no-index packaging@https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2b/c681de3e1dbcd469537aefb15186b800209aa1f299d933d23b48d85c9d56/packaging-15.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ce1a869fe039fbf7e217df36c4653d1dbe657778b2d41709593a0003584405f4
Collecting packaging@ https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2b/c681de3e1dbcd469537aefb15186b800209aa1f299d933d23b48d85c9d56/packaging-15.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ce1a869fe039fbf7e217df36c4653d1dbe657778b2d41709593a0003584405f4 
from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2b/c681de3e1dbcd469537aefb15186b800209aa1f299d933d23b48d85c9d56/packaging-15.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ce1a869fe039fbf7e217df36c4653d1dbe657778b2d41709593a0003584405f4
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2b/c681de3e1dbcd469537aefb15186b800209aa1f299d933d23b48d85c9d56/packaging-15.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: packaging
Successfully installed packaging-15.3
```

Comment: It seems that having such a dependency prevents uploading to PyPi. Is there a plan to allow this maybe?