# pulling a git repo at a particular commit in python setup.py file

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a Python project where I am using the `maskrcnn_benchmark` project from facebook research.

In my continuous integration script, I create a virtual environment where I install this project with thee following steps:

```
 - git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark.git
- cd maskrcnn-benchmark
- git reset --hard 5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6
- python setup.py build develop
```

This works fine and installs everything in the virtual environment as it needs to be.

Now I have a `setup.py` for my project for packaging and deploying my app. How can I do the same in this `setup.py` file i.e. pull and build this repository from the particular commit hash?

Thanks to the answer below and the comments, I have the setup.py as follows now:

```
install_requires=[
        '5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6-0.1',
        'ninja',
        'yacs',
        'matplotlib',
        'cython==0.28.5',
        'pymongo==3.7.1',
        'scipy==1.1.0',
        'torch==1.0.0',
        'torchvision==0.2.1',
        'opencv_python==3.4.2.17',
        'numpy==1.15.1',
        'gputil==1.3.0',
        'scikit_learn==0.19.2',
        'scikit_image==0.14.0',
        'sk_video==1.1.10'
  ],

dependency_links=[
        'http://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/tarball/master#egg=5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6-0.1'
  ],
```

No matter where I put the `'5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6-0.1'`, the `maskrcnn-benchmark` project gets compiled first. How can I do it that the dependency and this package is installed last?

Comment: Can't use `dependency_links=[
        "git+ssh://git@xxxxx.git"
    ]` ?

Comment: @GovindParashar I see this but can I pull the project at the specific commit? The `git reset --hard` step?

Comment: you can specify commit hash in the url i.e. master#egg=XXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: @GovindParashar Thank you. Let me try and update the thread here. Please feel free to write as an answer if you wish

Comment: for i.e. https://github.com/GovindParashar136/spring-boot-web-jsp/tarball/master#egg=8138cc3fd4e11bde31e9343c16c60ea539f687d9

Comment: Welcome @Luca I have added answer.

Comment: @GovindParashar tried your suggestion but it seems that the downloaded tarball never gets installed, even though it has a setup.py file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dependency_links` setup.py

i.e.

```
dependency_links =[https://github.com/GovindParashar136/spring-boot-web-jsp/tarball/master#egg=8138cc3fd4e11bde31e9343c16c60ea539f687d9]
```

In your case url

```
https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/tarball/master#egg=5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6
```

Comment: So, I tried the following in the dependency links: `https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/tarball/master#egg=5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6-0.1'. The project has a `setup.py` file. I can see it gets downloaded but it never gets installed. Do I need to do something else to get it to install it? I added the `0.1` as I saw that it is needed to add the version number.

Comment: you have to specify --process-dependency-links while using pip

Comment: I have seen dependency links processing has been deprecated.

Comment: but I am invoking it as `python setup.py build install`. So not using pip directly from the command line

Comment: Then you have add `install_requires=[
        '5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6-0.1'
    ],` before dependency_links

Comment: Thank you. At least that tries to compile the thing. So, is it possible to change the order of installation. It seems it processes the dependency first now and the install order gets messed up. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: If your issue resolved then please accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234885/56711) suggests that including a `package@` prefix to the git url will install the git commit specified:

```py
# in setup.py
setup(
    # other fields
    install_requires=[
        "packagename@git+https://github.com/<user>/<repo>#<commit hash>",
    ],
)
```

so in your case:

```py
# in setup.py
setup(
    # other fields
    install_requires=[
        "maskrcnn_benchmark@git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark.git#5ec0b91cc85163ac3b58265b3f9b39bb327d0ba6",
    ],
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to target a commit for a package that has an entry in pypi

Comment: Right, I get "Invalid requirement:" for my packet with the Pypi entry